# codeigniter4 - How do I shorten the path to the view folder for modules?

Tags: codeigniter-4

Based on a video with Codeigniter4, I created the Modules folder on the ROOTPATH and the Controllers, Views..etc folders in the Modules folder. It works fine, but when I want to call my view file inside the module

```
<?php 
namespace Modules\Giris\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
class IndexController extends BaseController
{
    public function index(){
        return view('Modules\Giris\Views\index');
    }
}
```

I need to specify a very long path like How can I make it just like view('index') and call the file from the Views folder in that module if I write it in a module? I don't want to write "Modules\Login\Views" in short is this possible?

Thanks in advance for all the kind replies.

Comment: You can define it as constant and reuse it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Because view requires a string you couldn't provide a namespaced reference as you might think you should. Furthermore the code adds a .php extension and the "view path" (defined in your config\paths file) as part of its process (see `system/View/View.php and render()`). Therefore without modifying Codeigniter (which could be done but would affect all your code) the easiest way is to simply declare a public property or constant and make reference to that instead. Also helps if you need to change the path at any point.

I.e. `protected $path = 'Modules\Giris\Views\'` and then `view($this->path.'index');` is probably the easiest way.